# При клике страница прокручивается вверх

Tags: jquery, html, css

Есть такой скрипт для увеличения/уменьшения значения в инпутах http://jsfiddle.net/aEYMb/30/

```js
$(function () {
    $('.plus-button').click(function () {
        var input = $(this).parents('.number').find('.form-field-1');
        if (input.val().length === 0){
            input.val('0');
        }
        var count = input.val();
        count++;
        input.val(count);       
    });
    
    $('.minus-button').click(function () {
        var input = $(this).parents('.number').find('.form-field-1');  
        if (input.val().length !== 0){
           var count = input.val();
            count--;
            if (count === 0) {
                input.val('');
            }
            else
            {
                input.val(count);  
            }
        }      
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background: #000;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.sorts {
    background: url(../images/bg_sorts.png) top left repeat-x;
    position: relative;
    height: 248px;
}
.sorts-1 {
    width: 960px;
}
.sorts-list {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 32px;
}
.sorts-list > li {
    float: left;
    width: 162px;
}
.number {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
.form-field-1 {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/k7aNJIh.png) center top no-repeat;
    width: 31px;
    height: 21px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #403a34;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
.minus-button, .plus-button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    color: #bab3af;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.minus-button {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/MbI0Vjq.png) center top no-repeat;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
.plus-button {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/MbI0Vjq.png) center top no-repeat;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
.rate {
    width: 110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="feedback-form-1">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="sorts sorts-1">
            <ul class="sorts-list">
                <li class="sort-1">
                    <div class="rate">
                        <div class="number"> <a class="minus-button" href="#">&ndash;</a>

                            <input class="form-field-1" type="text" name="sort-1" value="" /><a class="plus-button" href="#">+</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="sort-2">
                    <div class="rate">
                        <div class="number"> <a class="minus-button" href="#">&ndash;</a>

                            <input class="form-field-1" type="text" name="sort-2" value="" /><a class="plus-button" href="#">+</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="sort-3">
                    <div class="rate">
                        <div class="number"> <a class="minus-button" href="#">&ndash;</a>

                            <input class="form-field-1" type="text" name="sort-3" value="" /><a class="plus-button" href="#">+</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- sorts-1 -->
```

Но на странице при клике на ссылку страница прокручивается вверх.
Можно заменить `<a>` на какой-то другой элемент, а не заменяя `<a>` избежать прокручивания страницы можно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Но на странице при клике на ссылку страница прокручивается вверх.

Срабатывает переход по ссылке? Вы это имеете ввиду? Если да, то preventDefault Вам поможет.

```
$('linkSelector').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    /*dome code here*/       
});
```

Comment: Да, именно, спасибо!